# How can I work around skolemization errors in this Haskell code?

Tags: haskell, existential-type, rank-n-types

I have the following Haskell code

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, TypeOperators, ExistentialQuantification #-}

newtype Forall p = Forall (forall a. p a)
data Exists p = forall a. Exists !(p a)

newtype p :-> b = ForallFun (forall a. p a -> b)
data b :~> p = forall a. ExistsFun !(b -> p a)

newtype EmuExists p = EmuExists (forall b. (p :-> b) -> b)
data EmuForall p = forall b. EmuForall b (b :~> p)

toEmuForall :: Forall p -> EmuForall p
toEmuForall (Forall x) = EmuForall x (ExistsFun (\y -> y))

toEmuExists :: Exists p -> EmuExists p
toEmuExists (Exists x) = EmuExists (\(ForallFun f) -> f x)

fromEmuForall :: EmuForall p -> Forall p
fromEmuForall (EmuForall x (ExistsFun f)) = Forall (f x)

fromEmuExists :: EmuExists p -> Exists p
fromEmuExists (EmuExists f) = Exists (f (ForallFun (\x -> x)))
```

I am trying to emulate universal quantification in term of existential quantification using the logical formula

```
(∀a. P(a) → b) → b = ∃a. P(a)
```

And I think the dual formula is:

```
∀a. P(a) = ∃b. b ∧ (∃a. b → P(a))
```

But I can't get the from functions to work.

Comment: `∀a. P(a) = ∃b. b ∧ (∃a. b → P(a))` is not correct. Indeed, `∃b. b ∧ (∃a. b → P(a)) = a. P(a)`.

And, I don't off the top of my head know if there is a dualization of the previous formula that works in an intuitionist setting.